# Display Product_Category tag above the product titles in archives page

Tags: php, categories, hook-woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I have a shop that sells pictures.

Each picture is sub-categorized by its artist.

I want the artist name (sub-category) to display above the product title.

The following code targets the place I want it to be :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','add_artist_name', 9);

function add_artist_name() {

        echo 'artiste name';
    
}
```

[image]

I tried to duplicate the code that runs the category name on the single product page but it doesn't work and add bugs along the way.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','add_artist_name', 9);

function add_artist_name() {

    echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' );

    
}
```

Can you tell me why adding that line doesn't work and what is the fix ?

Furthermore, I would like only the subcategory to display.

As always, many thanks.

Comment: _"Can you tell me why adding that line doesn't work"_ - because no variable named `$product` exists in your function. _"and what is the fix ?"_ - you'll probably need to "import" the global $product variable, by putting `global $product;` as the first line of your function.

Comment: Thanks that a start, now it's displaying exactly like on the product page. Now, I need to trim down the "list" because it displays all the categories linked to the product.